# How can you tell the degree of a polynomial graph WITHOUT using calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

Consider a graph like this:

> [image: Polynomial graph]

Let's assume that there is no zero with a multiplicity greater than $3$. How can one tell the (least possible) degree? We know it's even, because the end behavior extends in the same direction. Adding up the multiplicities yields $6$, but how do we know it's not $8$, or $10$, or $276$ and is just translated in such a way that there are only $3$ x-intercepts?

Also, would counting turns and adding $1$ work in this case?

Comment: I see 5 turns.. so that it would be degree 5+1 = 6

Comment: How did you count 5 turns; I only see 4

Comment: on the left side of the y-axis there are 2 turns.

Comment: I see only 1, without counting the initial segment of the graph.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcLwC.png

Comment: imagine you are walking on the curve. You then turn left, right, left, right, left.

Comment: So you're counting the flat portion of the x-intercept? That seems odd and unreliable; will this method of counting turns work for every single polynomial graph?

Comment: There is no "flat portion" in a polynomial which is not constant. It is not possible otherwise the polynomial would have infinitely many roots. As for the counting turns method... well I don't know, it is the first time I hear about it. Also, the problem of these "graphs" is that there may be a fair amount of turns on the interval $[20,30]$ which is not shown in your plot.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't count turns.  Think of the graph of $y=x^8.$

If a zero is simple, the graph crosses the $x$-axis like a line.  In your graph, this happens at $x=9$.  If a zero has even multiplicity, the graph won't cross the $x$-axis, but touch it and turn back.  This happens at $x=4$.  So there must be at least two more zeros.   If a zero has odd multiplicity greater than one, the graph crosses the $x$-axis like a cubic.  This happens at $x=-3.$  So that's at least three more zeros.  So you polynomial has at least degree $6$.

If you graph $(x+3)^3(x-4)^2(x-9)$ it should look a lot like your graph.